# rvest: selecting a link based on link text

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping, rvest

I am attempting to scrape a number of webpages in which the link I need is in different positions (so CSS selectors are different), but the text remains the same. I want to be able to select the link based on its text, so I can then scrape that link for use later.

Here's an example of what I've tried:

```
test <- read_html("http://www.yaroslavl.vybory.izbirkom.ru/region/yaroslavl?action=show&global=true&root=762000007&tvd=276200077535&vrn=1001000882950&prver=0&pronetvd=null&region=76&sub_region=76&type=0&vibid=276200077535", encoding = "windows-1251")

test %>% html_nodes(xpath="//a[contains(text(), 'Сводная таблица о результатах выборов')]/@href")
```

However this always returns `{xml_nodeset (0)}` despite the link text being directly copied from the output of `test %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_text()`.

Is there another way I can try to select a link based on text? Also, is this possibly an encoding issue? The website is encoded in windows-1251, and I've saved my R file in this encoding as well.

Comment: What version of rvest are you using? When I run your code I get `{xml_nodeset (1)}` followed by href = the link, so I can't repeat your error. If it is just the link you want you might want to consider changing your code to: `test %>%
  html_nodes(xpath="//a[contains(text(), 'Сводная таблица о результатах выборов')]") %>% 
  html_attr('href')`

Comment: @Amanda I'm using 0.3.2 (so the latest version). This code and your example code still both return nothing for me. Are you using a Unix-like OS? That might confirm that this is an encoding issue.

Comment: I was running it on a Windows machine, are you on Unix? And have you checked the versions of the rvest dependencies?

Comment: Yes, it seemed to be an issue with an old version of magrittr. Not sure how that didn't get updated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to actually be an issue with not having the `stringi` package up-to-date, which is not a dependency but a recommended package. I would suggest that anyone experiencing encoding issues with `rvest` to try updating this package first.